# Extracting values from function output based on being greater than or less than

Tags: r, math, dataframe, arithmetic-expressions

I have created multiple functions using this code:

```
getT <- function(df, ID, Number){
  df %>%
    group_by(ID, Number) %>% 
    mutate( Distance = finish - begin) %>% 
    select(-begin,-finish,-symbols) %>%
    nest() %>% 
    mutate( data = map( data, ~ filter(.x, Distance == max(Distance)))) %>% 
    unnest()
}

getallT <- as.data.frame(getT(df))

getTID <- function(df, ID) {
  df1 <- getallT(df)
  subset(x = getallT, subset = (ID))
}`
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
ID     Number     Time     Distance
33         1      2.00         870
33         2      1.98         859
33         3      0.82         305
33         4      2.02         651
33         5      2.53         502
```

I am wondering if there is a way to extract the `Time` values based on how low or high the value is? In the case of above, I would like to create a function that could extract the values that were above 2.00 so it would have an output like this instead:

```
ID     Number     Time     Distance
33         4      2.02         651
33         5      2.53         502
```

Eventually, I would like to create a different function to extract the values that are below 1.00 and then go further by creating another different function for the combination of the two but I think I can do that once I know how to do the first part! Any response is much appreciated.

Comment: you could use `dplyr::filter(df, Time > 2.00)`

Comment: df[df$Time> 2, ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(33,5),
                 Number=1:5,
                 Time=c(2.00,1.98,0.82,2.02,2.53),
                 Distance=c(870,859,305,651,502))
```

You can keep values <=1 and >=2 with `filter`, `between` and `!`

```
df <- df %>% filter(!between(Time,1,2))

  ID Number Time Distance
1 33      3 0.82      305
2 33      4 2.02      651
3 33      5 2.53      502
```

Comment: I've used your suggested code which has been great, thanks! But now I've across an issue so now I'm left wondering how to either:
A. Filter out `Number` 4 & 5 
OR
B. Create a different `Time` filter specifically for `Number` 4 & 5.

I tried doing A. by using `filter(between(ID, 1,3)` but doesn't work.
I would rather go with B though if possible. So something like...
For ID numbers 1-3: `filter(!between(Time,1,2))`
For ID numbers 1-4: `filter(!between(Time 1.5,2.3))`
within the same function.

I've been trying out a few things for the past day but keep getting error messages.

Comment: If you only want values <= 1, you can do `df %>% filter(Time<=1)`